# Disable Fabric in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-activity, react-native-fast-image

I'm using React Native 0.71.x in my project and have `react-native-fast-image` which does not support the latest Fabric architecture. So I'd like to disable it if possible. How do I go about doing this? I haven't set up anything specifically for fabric so I guess it is enabled by default.

Comment: I'm using react-native-maps and as of today, it's still not compatible with Fabric https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4383

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow what is said in [React Native's documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.69/new-architecture-app-renderer-android) to enable it, and do the opposite.

Assuming that you're coding an app for Android:

### MyApplication.java

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
    new ReactNativeHost(this) {

      // Remove those lines:
      @Nullable
      @Override
      protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
        return new JSIModulePackage() {
          @Override
          public List<JSIModuleSpec> getJSIModules(
              final ReactApplicationContext reactApplicationContext,
              final JavaScriptContextHolder jsContext) {
            final List<JSIModuleSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
            specs.add(new JSIModuleSpec() {
              @Override
              public JSIModuleType getJSIModuleType() {
                return JSIModuleType.UIManager;
              }

              @Override
              public JSIModuleProvider<UIManager> getJSIModuleProvider() {
                final ComponentFactory componentFactory = new ComponentFactory();
                CoreComponentsRegistry.register(componentFactory);
                final ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = getReactInstanceManager();

                ViewManagerRegistry viewManagerRegistry =
                    new ViewManagerRegistry(
                        reactInstanceManager.getOrCreateViewManagers(
                            reactApplicationContext));

                return new FabricJSIModuleProvider(
                    reactApplicationContext,
                    componentFactory,
                    new EmptyReactNativeConfig(),
                    viewManagerRegistry);
              }
            });
            return specs;
          }
        };
      }
    };
}
```

#### gradle.properties

```
# Set this line to false
newArchEnabled=true
```